# Plot values in ggplot geom_lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(OBBLIGATORIO = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("no", 
"yes"), class = "factor"), COUNTRY = structure(c(16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", 
"Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Estonia", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", 
"Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", 
"Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", 
"Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"
), class = "factor"), YEAR = c(2003L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1995L, 1996L, 
1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2006L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1995L, 
1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2006L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L), AGE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Total", class = "factor"), 
    `CAUSE OF DEATH` = c("Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", 
    "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", 
    "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", 
    "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", 
    "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", "Acute poliomyelitis", 
    "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", 
    "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", 
    "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Diphtheria", "Measles", 
    "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", 
    "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", "Measles", 
    "Measles", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", 
    "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", 
    "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tetanus", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", 
    "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", 
    "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", 
    "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", "Tuberculosis", 
    "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", 
    "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", 
    "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", 
    "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", 
    "Viral hepatitis", "Viral hepatitis", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", 
    "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", 
    "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", 
    "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough", "Whooping cough"
    ), VALUE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 8L, 17L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 
    15L, 19L, 11L, 10L, 25L, 24L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 34L, 32L, 
    31L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
    33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", 
    "2", "3", "6", "7", "9", "17", "18", "19", "21", "22", "27", 
    "28", "30", "31", "37", "41", "42", "301", "329", "333", 
    "344", "350", "396", "413", "415", "460", "517", "558", "597", 
    "609", "622", "647", "681", "1087", "1349", "1413", "1448", 
    "1499", "1576", "1654", "1725", "1948", "2531", "2665", "2757"
    ), class = "factor"), ID = 1:98), .Names = c("OBBLIGATORIO", 
"COUNTRY", "YEAR", "AGE", "CAUSE OF DEATH", "VALUE", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, 
-98L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to obtain a chart that:

- on x axis there are values from YEAR column
- on y axis there are
- values from VALUE column data are divided by CAUSE OF DEATH column

So something like:
[image]

I try:

```
x11()
ggplot(df, aes(x = df$`YEAR`, y = df$`VALUE`, fill = df$`CAUSE OF DEATH`, colour = df$`CAUSE OF DEATH`)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1) +
  xlim(1995, 2010)
```

But the result is completely different from the one I want.

Thanks

Comment: You need to run `ggplot(df, aes(x = df$YEAR, y = df$VALUE, group = df$`CAUSE OF DEATH`, colour = df$`CAUSE OF DEATH`)) +
  geom_line()`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Cause of death is categorical. How you want to divide value by a categorical value? Please adjust the data example. Make sure that is contains all the variable you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your actual question is, but one problem with your dataframe is that the `VALUE` column is currently defined as a **factor**, not as as a **numeric**.  I think that remedying this will go a long way to solving your problem.  I do this post-facto below (i.e. after the dataframe is already created), but if you are getting the data into R via a `read.table()` or similar command, you can specify the `class` of your columns at data frame creation time, which is probably a better approach.

In my code below I use the `dplyr` package for manipulating dataframes.  It's quite powerful, but for this particular example it isn't doing anything that base R couldn't do.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

df <- ### YOUR dput output goes here ###

# fix the problem with the `VALUE` column
df %<>% mutate(VALUE = VALUE %>% as.character %>% as.numeric)

# equivalent in base R:
#   df$VALUE <- as.numeric(as.character(df$VALUE))

# make a graph (is it the one you want?)
df %>% group_by(YEAR, `CAUSE OF DEATH`) %>% 
       summarize(value = sum(VALUE)) %>% 
       ggplot(aes(x = YEAR, y = value, color = `CAUSE OF DEATH`)) +
            geom_line() + 
            theme_bw() +
            geom_point()

# save graph for uploading to SO
ggsave('SO37230266.png')
```

The result is this graph:

[image]